# Locating iFrames and controls within them using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: selenium, iframe, webdriver

I'm trying to automate www.snapdeal.com using Selenium Webdriver. I'm not able to click a web element inside an iframe as I get Element not visible exception.

Below is the code snippet

```
package com.snapdeal.framework.rough;

import java.util.List;

import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.JavascriptExecutor;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.interactions.Actions;

public class Lab {

    public static WebDriver browser;
    public static WebElement currentElement;
    public static Actions actions;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", System.getProperty("user.dir")+"//src//main//resources//chromedriver.exe");
        browser = new FirefoxDriver();
        browser.get("http://www.snapdeal.com");
        browser.manage().window().maximize();
        browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='pincodeSalienceComponent']/div[2]/i")).click();
        actions = new Actions(browser);
        actions.moveToElement(browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='accountHeader']/div[1]"))).perform();
        actions.moveToElement(browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='accountHeader']/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/p/span[2]"))).click().build().perform();
        //By executing a java script
        JavascriptExecutor exe = (JavascriptExecutor) browser;
        Integer numberOfFrames = Integer.parseInt(exe.executeScript("return window.length").toString());
        System.out.println("Number of iframes on the page are " + numberOfFrames);

        //By finding all the web elements using iframe tag
        List<WebElement> iframeElements = browser.findElements(By.tagName("iframe"));
        System.out.println(iframeElements.get(0));
        System.out.println("The total number of iframes are " + iframeElements.size());

        try{
            browser.switchTo().frame(1);
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        try{
            browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-register-modal']/div[2]/div[2]/div[2]/div")).click();
        }catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println(e.getMessage());
        }

        browser.close();
    }

}
```

Could you please guide me on how to get this resolved?

Comment: I need to select Account - Register menu option and click the Mobile number and email button.

Answer (score 0):

You need to [switch to iframe](http://www.seleniumhq.org/docs/03_webdriver.jsp#moving-between-windows-and-frames):

```
// click Mobile number and email button first an then
driver.switchTo().frame("loginIframe");
// after registration is done switch back to top frame:
driver.switchTo().defaultContent();
```

Comment: The below code solved the issue for me browser.switchTo().frame("loginIframe");
   browser.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='login-register-modal']/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div")).click();